# how to call multiple request in angular and get result together?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use `forkJoin` in angular to hit multiple requests asynchronously and  get data together.I do like that but getting below error

here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3jpqrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

(this request not work on https `http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=`)

**service code**

```
getcalculation(n:number){
    const url = 'http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr='+n+'*'+n;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

**component code**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.showAddButton = true;

    for(let i =0;i <this.item.length;i++){
      this.allSubScription$.push(this.dataservice.getcalculation(i));
    }

    forkJoin(this.allSubScription$).subscribe((result)=>{
      console.log(result)
    },(err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })

  }
```

on local, I am getting this error

[image]

Comment: Im getting this error  `cannot load http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=2*2. Failed to start loading.` , `was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint` , `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`  it seems that your problem in server side, are you getting the same error?

Comment: as I already mention it will not work on `https`

Comment: in your stackBlitz, forget {headers:...}. Just fetchDataThroughPromise(){
    return this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
  }, see your stackbilz forked in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-waarr2

Answer (score 0):

Implements the following code, add just the `allSubScription$` array into the `forkJoin` and by using a subscribe, the response is going to be an array with each api request.

```
 for(let i =0;i <this.item.length;i++){
      this.allSubScription$.push(this.dataservice.getcalculation(i));
    }

    forkJoin(
        this.allSubScription$
      ).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res[0]);
        console.log(res[1]);
        console.log(res[2]);
      })
```

I had problems to run the api url and I just force the response simulating the api response.
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vua1dk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: what happen when any of api fail

Comment: All the forkjoin fails